# what is the meaning of "traction back"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "traction back" in the sentence below?

> The salt and ice challenge gained **traction back** in 2012.

Comment: I think you're parsing that wrong. It "gained traction", back in the year 2012.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a mis-parsing of the sentence.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence makes more sense if you break it up this way:

- The salt and ice challenge (gained traction) (back in 2012).

"gained traction" means "became important", or "increased in importance" (or "increased in salience", or "significance".) Here the meaning is therefore "became important back in 2012."